# invalidateQueries doesn't refetch/refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a button that, on click, has to perform a thing that makes a list displayed on my page to change, and in theory the page should reload. However, that never happens, no matter how many times I click my button.

Full code of my button:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSaveOrderItemsForList } from '../../hooks/Lists/useSaveOrderItemsForList';
import ErrorIndicator from '../shared/ErrorIndicator';
import LoadingButton from '../shared/LoadingButton';
import { valueState as valueStateAtom } from '../../atoms/orderItemsAtom';
import { useSetRecoilState } from 'recoil';

export default function SaveOrderItemsButton({ orderItems, listID }) {
    const { isError, error, isLoading, mutate } = useSaveOrderItemsForList(orderItems, listID);
    const setValue = useSetRecoilState(valueStateAtom);

    const handleClick = () => {
        mutate(orderItems, listID);
        setValue([]);
    }

    return (
        <div className={'w-100'}>
            <br />
            <ErrorIndicator isError={isError} error={error} />
            <LoadingButton
                className={'w-100'}
                variant={'success'}
                loading={isLoading}
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                Save
            </LoadingButton>
        </div>
    );
}
```

As for the code of my custom hook:

```
import { getToken } from '../../tokens/getToken';
import { basePath } from '../../config/basePath';
import { getTokenAuthHeaders } from '../../functions/sharedHeaders';
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';

async function saveOrderItemsForList(orderItems, listID) {
    const token = await getToken();
    const response = await fetch(`${basePath}/lists/save_order_items/${listID}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({ orderItems }),
        headers: getTokenAuthHeaders(token)
    });

    return response.json();
}

export function useSaveOrderItemsForList() {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    return useMutation(saveOrderItemsForList,
        {
            onSuccess: () => {
                return queryClient.invalidateQueries('lists');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

My theory is that, since I'm managing the organizing of my list client-side, the page doesn't get updated with the information I passed (this is the code of the page that shows the list):

```
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import CardsList from './CardsList';
import { useList } from '../../hooks/Cards/useList';
import useOrderItemsForCardsInList from '../../hooks/Lists/useOrderItemsForCardsInList';
import usePaginateCardsInList from '../../hooks/Cards/usePaginateCardsInList';
import LoadingAndErrorCentered from '../shared/LoadingAndErrorCentered';

export default function List({ listID }) {
    const { isLoading, isError, error, data } = useList(listID);
    const { data: orderItems } = useOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID);
    const pagesArray = usePaginateCardsInList(orderItems, data);

    return (
        <Col xs={12}>
            <br />
            <LoadingAndErrorCentered isLoading={isLoading} isError={isError} error={error} />
            {data && <CardsList cards={pagesArray} listID={listID} />}
        </Col>
    );
}
```

What do you guys think?

Edit: This is the code of my `useList` hook.

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { getTokenAuthHeaders } from '../../functions/sharedHeaders';
import { basePath } from '../../config/basePath';
import { getToken } from '../../tokens/getToken';

async function getList(listID) {
    const token = await getToken();
    const response = await fetch(`${basePath}/cards/list/${listID}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: getTokenAuthHeaders(token)
    });

    return response.json();
}

export function useList(listID) {
    return useQuery(['cards', 'list', listID], () => {
        return getList(listID);
    });
}
```

and on my server, I have this function declared on my endpoint:

```
static async getList(id) {
   const query = await List.findById(id).exec();
   return query;
}
```

Comment: Does the useList hook return fresh data when the query is invalidated?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I just tested it and the useList hook doesn't return fresh data when the query is invalidated

Comment: That's why your component isn't getting new data then  =)  Post the useList hook?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I edited my question with the code of the useList hook :)

Comment: If I understand what that is doing, your query key is "cards". You invalidated a query with key "lists". If I understand it incorrectly (I'm new to react query so totally possible), it still has an 's' at the end of Lists so it's not the same key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries('lists');
```

vs

```
useQuery(['cards', 'list', listID], () => {});
```

You are not invalidating the right query keys, so naturally the query doesn't refetch. You need to use the correct key for invalidation, in your case:

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries(['cards', 'list']);
```